# Issue initialising the Tkinter button class when making an extension of it

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am using python 3.11 and Tkinter. I am making a colour palette creator using python and tkinter. I am using a class for the colors in the palette.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

import random

hexChars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F']

buttonCount = 4

class _Button(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
        self['bg'] = self.rand_hex()
        self['text'] = ''
        self['image'] = pixel
        self['width'] = 55
        self['height'] = 55
        self['command'] = self.choose_color
        self['compound'] = 'c'
        Button.pack(self, side=tk.LEFT)

    def choose_color(self):
        color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title ="Choose color")
        Button.configure(self, bg=color_code[1])

    def rand_hex(self):
        return '#' + random.choice(hexChars) + random.choice(hexChars) + random.choice(hexChars)

root = Tk()
pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

buttons = []
for i in range(buttonCount):
    buttons.append(_Button())

root.geometry(str((len(buttons)*61)+32) + "x50")
root.mainloop()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rufus_tyxwzbt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\color_picker.py", line 50, in <module>
    buttons.append(_Button())
                   ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rufus_tyxwzbt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\color_picker.py", line 22, in __init__
    Button.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rufus_tyxwzbt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2706, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\rufus_tyxwzbt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2622, in __init__
    self._setup(master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\rufus_tyxwzbt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2591, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Can somebody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `*args`, not `args` when calling the `__init__` method. `args` is a tuple, but the first argument needs to be a tkinter widget. That is why you see the error `tuple' object has no attribute 'tk'`: widgets have a "tk" attribute but you passed in a tuple.

```
Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
#                     ^^^^^
```